# Word for examining purchasing behavior of customers

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a basic principle in economics that says as follows: to find out what people demand, don't listen to their words (what they claim to want) but rather examine their actual purchasing choices.
What is the term for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_voting

Comment: Want to make it an answer?

Comment: Gotta commute, anyone's free to take it.

Comment: There are similar concepts in UX and design. User behavior is often different than user claims of behavior.

Comment: Yeah, in voting too, especially on social issues.

Comment: There are several terms.  "Market research" is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RegDwight has promptly suggested, the expression you are looking for is 
***dollar voting***:

> - In economics, ***[dollar voting](http://www.investordictionary.com/definition/dollar-voting)*** is an analogy used to explain how the purchasing choices of consumers affect which products will continue to be produced and supplied to the market. *Every dollar paid for a particular product may be considered a "dollar vote" for that product, such that the products with the largest number of dollar votes generate the most profit and will therefore continue to be produced.*
> - The reference to "dollar" is just an example; the principle holds for any currency.

(www.investordictionary.com)

Comment: I think I'm looking for a term that suggests that people will claim to like red coats, but actually buy blue ones.

Comment: @thumbtackthief - are you referring to this? ***The black box model*** shows the interaction of stimuli, consumer characteristics, decision process and consumer responses. It can be distinguished between interpersonal stimuli (between people) or intrapersonal stimuli (within people). The black box model is related to the black box theory of behaviorism, where the focus is not set on the processes inside a consumer, but the relation between the stimuli and the response of the consumer. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_behaviour#Purchase_decision